# How can I run multiple runs of pipeline with different config files - issue with lock on .snakemake directory

Tags: snakemake

I am running a snakemake pipeline from the same working directory but with different config files and the input / output are in different directories too. The issue seems to be that although both runs are using data in different folders snakemake creates the lock on the pipeline folder due to the .snakemake folder and the lock folder within. Is there a way to force separate .snakemake folders? code example below:

Both runs are ran from within /home/pipelines/qc_pipeline :

run 1:

```
/home/apps/miniconda3/bin/snakemake -p -k -j 999 --latency-wait 10 --restart-times 3 --use-singularity --singularity-args "-B /pipelines_test/QC_pipeline/PE_trimming/,/clusterTMP/testingQC/,/home/www/codebase/references" --configfile /clusterTMP/testingQC/config.yaml --cluster-config QC_slurm_roadsheet.json --cluster "sbatch --job-name {cluster.name} --mem-per-cpu {cluster.mem-per-cpu} -t {cluster.time} --output {cluster.output}"
```

run 2:

```
/home/apps/miniconda3/bin/snakemake -p -k -j 999 --latency-wait 10 --restart-times 3 --use-singularity --singularity-args "-B /pipelines_test/QC_pipeline/SE_trimming/,/clusterTMP/testingQC2/,/home/www/codebase/references" --configfile /clusterTMP/testingQC2/config.yaml --cluster-config QC_slurm_roadsheet.json --cluster "sbatch --job-name {cluster.name} --mem-per-cpu {cluster.mem-per-cpu} -t {cluster.time} --output {cluster.output}"
```

error:

```
Directory cannot be locked. Please make sure that no other Snakemake process is trying to create the same files in the following directory:
/home/pipelines/qc_pipeline
If you are sure that no other instances of snakemake are running on this directory, the remaining lock was likely caused by a kill signal or a power loss. It can be removed with the --unlock argument.
```

Comment: Are you certain these multiple instances of pipeline don't produce any of the same output files? Even sharing a single output will cause this problem.

Comment: They write to completely different directories, the only issue is the .snakemake folder. Using the --nolock solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maarten-vd-Sande correctly points to the `--nolock` option (+1), but in my opinion it's a very bad idea to use `--nolock` routinely.

As the error says, two snakemake processes are trying to create the same file. Unless the error is a bug in snakemake, I wouldn't blindly proceed and overwrite files.

I think it would be safer to assign to each snakemake execution its own execution directory and working directory, like:

```
topdir=`pwd`

mkdir -p run1 
cd run1
snakemake --configfile /path/to/config1.yaml ... 
cd $topdir

mkdir -p run2
cd run2 
snakemake --configfile /path/to/config2.yaml ...
cd $topdir

mkdir -p run3
etc...
```

---

**EDIT**

Actually, it should be less clunky and probably better to use the the `--directory/-d` option:

```
snakemake -d run1 --configfile /path/to/config1.yaml ...
snakemake -d run2 --configfile /path/to/config2.yaml ...
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed my code to do just that and it's working great now.

Comment: @dariober, thanks, that solution generally does the trick, but leads snakemake to download 6GB of conda environments for each working directory that I call it for. Is there a way to avoid that, and instead reuse the environments?

Comment: okay, there is the `--conda-prefix` option in snakemake that I just discovered. but slowly, my snakemake call accumulates more and more arugments that one needs to keep in mind for it to work properly. i'd rather have that automagically working... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the different pipelines do **not** generate the same output files you can do it with the `--nolock` option:

```
snakemake --nolock [rest of the command]
```

Take a look [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#how-does-snakemake-lock-the-working-directory) for a short doc about `nolock`.

Comment: @JP_gvtech take a look at the answer of dariober. Might be more appropriate