# How to have multiple users run the same pipeline in snakemake - metadata permissions issue

Tags: python, permissions, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs, collaboration

I have a pipeline that we want to store in a shared space so that all our analysts can access it and use it without having to copy the repo / singularity container. The problem is when one person runs the pipeline the files in .snakemake/metadata belong to that user. When the next user tries to run the pipeline this metadata is accessed and causes an error.

I know I could delete the data in metadata at the end of the process but ideally we want users to be able to run the pipeline in parallel (on different inputs / output). All users are within the same group but this doesn't not help

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure how well this scales, but what if you set the permissions to the metadata to 777 (775 might also work). `chmod -R 777 .snakemake/metadata`

Comment: Isn't this basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59642199/how-can-i-run-multiple-runs-of-pipeline-with-different-config-files-issue-with? If I understand correctly, my answer there should fix also this.

Comment: @dariober does setting the working directory also changes the location of the .snakemake directory?

Comment: @dariober thank you, I set a working directory and a directory where all the pipeline code is stored (within the snake file) so I can run the pipeline from anywhere as multiple users / in parallel. works great now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59668814/10693596) is to use `-d` or `--directory` option to specify a custom working directory for each user. This way each user has their own `.snakemake` directory.

To automate this, one can use a dedicated shell script or an alias that will automatically specify a user-specific path:

```bash
snakemake -d ".snakemake_$(whoami)"
```

(for Windows, one can reference a suitable environment variable instead of `whoami`)

Where appropriate, it might be better to use a softer solution. Specifically, the earlier approach still exposes the whole workflow to each user, potentially creating conflicts due to one user making changes that another user is unaware of.

To avoid this, it might be better to host the workflow (snakefiles) in a central (edit-protected) location, but require that users run the code in their own folders referencing a common workflow location using `-s` or `--snakefile` argument. This way changes in the central location can occur only when the designated users make them, so any workflow adjustments that are needed are made explicitly.

Update: a clarification on the file paths when using the `--snakefile` option. For `input`/`output` the relative paths are changed to the current working directory. For `script`/`shell` and other directives, the relative paths are relative to the path of the `Snakefile`. [The details can be found here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project_info/faq.html#how-does-snakemake-interpret-relative-paths).

This behavior may or may not be suitable for a given use case. If all users are expected to work with the same files, then absolute paths can be provided (of course one risk here is that files could be modified during concurrent execution).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification! Regarding the `--snakefile` option, does it understand the current folder structure (e.g. ./workflow/scripts/ & ./config/ etc. )?

Comment: This one is tricky. For `input`/`output` the relative paths are changed to the current working directory (so either specify absolute paths or end up with each user having their own input/output files, which may/may not be acceptable to your use case). For  `script`/`shell` and other directives, the relative paths are relative to the path of the Snakefile. The details can be found [here.](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project_info/faq.html#how-does-snakemake-interpret-relative-paths)